# why nodejs readable stream skip the first letter?

Tags: node.js, stream

```
var util = require('util');
var ReadableStream = require('stream').Readable;

function MyReadStream() {
    ReadableStream.call(this);
    this._index = 0;
    this._string = 'Hello World!';
}

util.inherits(MyReadStream, ReadableStream);

MyReadStream.prototype._read = function() {
    var i = this._index++;
    if (i == this._string.length) {
      this.push(null);
      this.pipe(process.stdout);
    }
    else {
      var buf = new Buffer(this._string[i], 'utf8');
      this.push(buf);
    }
 };

 var readerInst = new MyReadStream();
 readerInst.read();
```

==============================================

Why I get stdout 'ello World!'  instead of  'Hello World!'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that the `readerInst.read()` (which asks for any number of bytes) causes `_read()` to be executed because there is no data to read yet, so `_read()` pushes the first character to the stream, which is then returned by `readerInst.read()`. After that call finishes, the rest of the string is pushed to the stream and when the end of the string has been reached, the contents are piped/written to stdout, which is only going to show the string starting from the second letter.

You can verify this is happening by logging the return value of `readerInst.read()`.

Comment: Because the `.push()` causes `._read()` to be called repeatedly until the highWaterMark is hit, which never happens because the string length is much smaller than the default highWaterMark.

Comment: But why not `readerInst._read()`  return the first character just as `readerInst.read()` ? What‘s the difference between `readerInst._read()` and `readerInst.read()` ？

Comment: The [streams documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/stream.html) describes the two methods. `_read()` doesn't return the first character because it's a very different method and not meant to be called directly.